# Refactor variable access in Android Studio? (Delegate to method)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a variable in a class:

```
public final class Things {
    public static final Thing OBJECT = new Thing();
}
```

I access it in various places with:

```
Things.OBJECT.someCoolMethod();
```

I want to use it like this:

```
Things.getObject().someCoolMethod();
```

**How can I acheive this automatically with refactoring? I dont want to have to go through each class accessing it manually (Its a huge project)**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you not just rename the variable to `getObject()`? I believe this will replace al `OBJECT` calls with `getObject()`. Then you can create the `getObject()` method and rename the variable to `OBJECT` manually again.

Comment: @RemcoW Cant use () unfortunately, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Mm that's unfortunate. You can look for all usages of the object so you don't have to search for the occurrences manually, but I don't think you can replace them.

Comment: @RemcoW Indeed. I have well over 1000 usages, so refactoring by hand is really the last option I want to jump into. Fingers crossed that someone has the answer.

Comment: @RemcoW You can see my answer for a solution. Hope that helps you as much as it did me :)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that was an option. I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

After some digging I found a solution. Hope that this will help other adventurers further down the road too.

**Right click variable > Refactor > Encapsulate Fields... > Getter**